# How to use lcd.write with String Array in Arduino

Tags: arrays, string, arduino, lcd

My code fragment is

```
String item[] = {"Hello","How","Where"};
int slot[] = {2,0,0};
i=0;
String t = item[slot[i]];
lcd.write(t);       //This gives error
```

How to eradicate the problem. I am a beginner with ArduinoIDE and microprocessors.
Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

It think you should use lcd.print instead of lcd.write. The function lcd.write write out single characters at a time, since you want to output a string you can use lcd.print instead.

```
lcd.print(t);
```

Also refer write and print on manual.
http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/LiquidCrystalWrite